# Pycharm Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment

Tags: linux, pycharm, fedora

I'm trying to setup Pycharm professional edition on Fedora 25 x64.
After downloading the files and extracting them, I'm trying to run the script `./pycharm.sh` in the bin directory.
This is the error I get:

```
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I have checked my Java version

```
[root@localhost bin]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

I tried as well to set the DISPLAY variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

And this is what I get:

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./pycharm.sh 
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: 1. Are you using Wayland? (It's the default.) 2. Do you _need_ to run this as root?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same error installing in a clean Ubuntu 17.10, with Gnome on Wayland. At @mattdm's suggestion in your comments, I just opened a new terminal (as myself, not root) and it ran fine. I was running as root (after unpacking everything to /opt/) when I got the error.

```
mike@feynman:~$ /opt/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh
```

Once you register/activate, just click the "* Configure v" pulldown from the welcome window, and select "Create Desktop Entry" to make it available from your OS menus. I'm assuming JetBrains made this work for whichever linux flavor you prefer.

Comment: on most distributions, to operate inside `/opt` you need root privilieges. I did unpack it in my home folder, and run it as standard user.

Comment: @tombishop83 Yes, that's correct. To use /opt, unpack it all as root, or with sudo, then execute it as a standard user.

Answer (score 5):

Your X environment is not properly set (manually setting `DISPLAY` doesn't always work). Possibly because you're attempting this as `root` and `root` is not the owner of the graphics session. There could be other reasons, too.

You won't be able to run `xclock` or any other X app either in this situation - this is the clue that it's not a `pycharm`-related problem. For example if you ssh to localhost as `root`, not as the user currently logged in into the graphical session:

```
laptop:~ # ssh localhost
Password: 
Last login: Thu Nov 23 22:19:06 2017 from localhost
Have a lot of fun...
laptop:~ # export DISPLAY=:0
laptop:~ # xclock
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
laptop:~ # konsole
No protocol specified
Segmentation fault
laptop:~ # pycharm
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment
```

You'd also see the same behaviour if you attempt the same in a text-mode console.

To address this issue open a new terminal from the graphics environment - if it is properly installed you should be able to run any of the X apps, including pycharm (or at least it shouldn't fail with that error).

Answer (score 2):

I have come across with this problem when using CLion yesterday.

setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable didn't work for me.

After a bit of trial & error installing the `clion-jre` package from AUR seems to solve it on my machine.

```
yay -S clion-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

**In fedora** 

I have installed pycharm using [fedy](http://folkswithhats.org/).  This is worked.
Or change to a another user and try except root. 
**Phpstrom, Webstrom, PyCharm**
Above three of them worked same like that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In my case I am runing pycharm through docker, which is different host, run command xhost + , this would disable access control and client would be able to connect from any host.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the program from another user instead of root. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenJDK instead of Oracle Java, because [PyCharm hangs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79500/pycharm-2017-3-3-hangs) on Raspberry Pi.

In the file `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`, disabling the entry `assistive_technologies` (simply comment out with a `#`) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the terminal and open again and try it, this worked for me

The reason it wasn't working was because you were in a rooted Id

Opening a fresh terminal return you back to your normal I'd.

Answer (score -1):

This is what resolved my issue:

```
export DISPLAY='localhost:11'
```