# X11 error when running Pycharm, Tkinter, and others

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm, x11, gksudo

Ahoy there, Whenever I try to run Pycharm as root from the terminal with:

```
sudo charm
```

Which returns this error:

```
    seth@pixel:~/programming/python/Spoofenschmirtz-Evil-incARPorated$ sudo charm

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '127.0.0.1:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:128)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1049)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
    at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
    at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:103)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

I tried running `gksu`, and got this:

```
(gksu:23822): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 127.0.0.1:0.0
```

Similarly, when I run my python project, which uses Tkinter:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 11, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2020, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

and this when I run `sudo gedit`:

```
    No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:4723): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 17.10, and I'm using a laptop, running off only the external display, if that's relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124295/pycharm-startup-error-unable-to-detect-graphics-environment)

Comment: So any X11 program you run with `sudo` cannot connect to the X server. Hmm, I wonder if this is some kind of recurring problem...