# Installing PyCharm on GCP vm

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, graphics, pycharm, environment

I am a novice linux user who uses `PyCharm` daily on a Windows 10 machine.
I tried to migrate one of my projects to the cloud using GCP vm (2 cpus, 7.5 gb memory)
I downloaded and extracted the `PyCharm` most recent release (`pycharm-community-2020.1.2.tar.gz`) following which I tried to launch `pycharm` by using the command (from a folder named `pycharm` to which the `.gz` was extracted):

```
pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh
```

The response I got:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I tried to install various graphical packages but still, got the same error.

HELP

Comment: Maybe see ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124295/pycharm-startup-error-unable-to-detect-graphics-environment

Comment: Did you add any GPU's to your VM instance ? If not you can do it even after it's created.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried various options - most time I spent on trying to get a Desktop and its prerequisites (e.e. Gnome, etc.) and got nowhere - I gave up for now...
It became too involved with each package necessitating a several other prerequisits and being a linux / unix / debian ignoramus, I gave up.