# PyCharm Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to Setup PyCharm Community on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) using Ubuntu. When trying to run it (`sh bin/pycharm.sh`) I receive following error:

> PyCharm Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124295/pycharm-startup-error-unable-to-detect-graphics-environment) post I have set `export DISPLAY=:0` and tried it as non-root, without success. I don't want to install PyCharm for Windows because I need to use the virtual environments inside the WSL. I also cannot install a native Ubuntu or use a VM.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is WSL can't output the graphical environment of PyCharm to Windows. I have solved the issue by exporting `DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` i.e. run:

```
echo 'export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then I had to install [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html), start WSL from inside MobaXTerm Terminal and run `pycharm.sh` from there.